# echoing file error on upload if there is an error

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once "core/init.php";

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    // File properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    // Work out the file extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'png');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) 
    {
        echo 'Your file will be processed shortly, thank you.';
    }

    if($file_error == true) 
    {
        echo 'Failed to upload file';
    }

    if($file_size <= 2097152) {

        $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
        $file_destination = 'profilepictures/' . $file_name_new;

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination));
            echo $destination;
    }
}
?>
```

Simple problem, just frustrated at the moment. I'm trying to get it to `echo Failed to upload file` on a failed upload, but it's doing it on a successful upload and failed upload. I get both messages, the successful one and failed one on good uploads, but when it's a bad upload I only get the failed one.

Comment: Try dumping `$file_error` on a successful upload - see what it says?

Answer (score 1):

`$file_error` will return a value (and will therefore be `true`) even if the upload is successful. [See PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Change your check to:

```
if($file_error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ //...
```

Or

```
if($file_error !== 0){ //...
```

Comment: Same thing is happening as I commented on the other answer I have

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `if($file_error == true)` by `if($file_error != 0)`

Here is the explanation : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I've actually done this method already, it doesn't echo my message with the `!` If I remove it, it will `echo` my message, but also shows up with the successful upload message on good uploads.

Comment: Where is the successful message ?

Comment: `if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) 
    {
        echo 'Your file will be processed shortly, thank you.';
    }`

Comment: Of course it will be shown, for example if your png file is transfert but it too heavy, it will validate the `in_array` test but not the `!= 0` test.

Comment: Well it was here and it still wasn't working right, it took place of echo $destination `if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)); {
            echo $destination;
    }`

Comment: You have to reorder your test conditions and perform nesting test.

Comment: I got it fixed, I redid the whole upload page a different way. It was easier to do that, than maybe still get an error redoing almost the same thing/style. I will up you for helping a bit. :p